# using mvn exec:java gives error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demoproject.demoProject.DemoProjectApplication

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to use `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.demoproject.demoProject.DemoProjectApplication"` but it gives error. Here's my pom.xml
Please review my work and help me fix this, I am not a java developer yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demoproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoProject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's the error I am getting https://pastebin.com/raw/A8P5pkL4
and here's the `/home/v2stech/Documents/DemoProject/demoProject/src/main/java/com/demoproject/demoProject/DemoProjectApplication.java` file: https://pastebin.com/GcnDDugm

Comment: have you checked whether or not that class actually exists?

Comment: your file name is 'demoproject.java', yet you try to call a class called 'DemoProjectApplication', which seems to be a public class inside the demoproject.java class? Stop what you're doing. Stop using Spring. Stop using maven. Get a textbook on Java and start with chapter 1, no matter how boring you think those first chapters are. You are trying to run a marathon, while you haven't learned how to walk yet.

Comment: I made a typing error. The file called DemoProjectApplcation.java does exist. It even worked on my co-workers computer. But I do agree about getting the java textbook part. I am open to recommendations

Comment: Welcome to the site darkdead - I suggest you follow a step-by-step tutorial from an trustworthy source for setting up your java environment and compiling your 1st project with maven.

Comment: @tucuxi Thanks! I am impressed by how fast the responses are. It looks like SDKMAN is very easy to setup something like this. So I will give that a try and look in to others as well because sdkman looks stupid easy.

Answer (score 1):

- try `mvn spring-boot:run`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.overriding-command-line

will be better.

Comment: `[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/v2stech/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/v2stech/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]`

Comment: Is this your first maven project? Have you ever compiled and packaged any programs with Maven on this machine?

Comment: I guess this is a environment and config problem.

Comment: Yes, this is my first maven project. I have never compiled any program or package before. But I did follow a tutorial for jkube and compiled the project which worked. Other than that I have never done anything related to java. How do I get my environment and config fixed? Is there a guide to start from beginning? I am on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04 too. I have not seen this `a tutorial for jkube`, so I can not try config step. I put my config step. I use sdkman to install jdk , maven.

Comment: The Jkube was a different project I used [this](https://faun.pub/deploying-spring-boot-application-on-kubernetes-using-kubernetes-maven-plugin-46caf22b03a5).Now I am tasked to use the same jkube project but I have to use maven to execute npm build. I found the exec-maven-plugin and  frontend-maven-plugin so as a trial I borrowed my co-worker's demo project (The one I posted about) which is this one. But I wasn't even able to run it in the first place, for some reason it worked now but I am still stuck at the jkube part.